# Why was the question about the future of laptops closed?

Tags: support, closed-questions, moderation

I suggest you to go through these questions first:

[Why are we still using CPUs instead of GPUs?](https://superuser.com/questions/308771/why-are-we-still-using-cpus-instead-of-gpus)

[Desktops turned into Laptops and these laptops turn into..!!?](https://superuser.com/questions/421817/desktops-turned-into-laptops-and-these-laptops-turn-into#comment482892_421817)

In the first question some one asked why we are not using the technology which is already available. It may be like asking why you are still using desktops when there are laptops available with advanced technology?

Now (in the second question which asked by me) I wonder why my question is closed saying that it's just something which leads to argument or debate.

Moreover, people are downvoting the question which is already closed. In my question I talked about things which we can't do with desktops but can be done with laptops using advanced technology.

I just asked about the next coming technology or next generation computers. Maybe something that already exists or is under development. Do people think the technology will end up with laptops? Is there no other advanced existing or coming technology to laptops?

Now some one can explain **me what makes it different?** And **why was my question closed?**

I'm not asking you to explain the reasons here but just want to know exact difference so that I won't repeat such mistakes again.

Comment: Generally speaking, "some other question that is vaguely similar to mine wasn't closed, so why was mine" is a poor way to gain support for reopening your question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick comment @nhinkle. But I'm really sorry to say like this I only requested for exact difference of those questions so that I can avoid next time such mistakes. I never asked to close the other question or never requested to reopen my question. All I want to know finally Whats the next advanced technology to laptops?

Answer (score 7):

> In the first question some one asked why we are not using the technology which is already available.

First question asks what prevents GPUs being used as CPUs.

> may be like asking why you are still using desktops when there are laptops available with advanced technology?

No, I have no clue how you arrive at that.

Your question asks

> But now I wonder what the next form of these laptops? In the coming days what kind of shape these laptops are going to take?

Your question is speculative, subjective & polling. There's no way with certainty your question can be answered with what will come up.

I don't see how that can be objectively answered, while the first question can be answered with facts and analysis.

Comment: thanks for your quick answer sathya but I asked about the next coming technology which going to come after laptops? Is there no such technology existed or under development? wont come any advanced technology with more features? cant anyone answer to that by explaining the next generation technology?

Comment: @user113701 over at [su], we don't talk about what-may-come because in essence everyone will have their own opinion and it becomes a big discussion fest. Once you've earned more than 20 rep, you're welcome to talk & discuss about it in our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access)

Comment: @user113701 There's no point in doing this (unless you get paid for it) because it's almost inevitably wrong. Look up a few mobile phone market analyst reports from just five years ago on what the future (i.e. today) would look like. These sites are about creating a repository of useful knowledge, not horribly wrong predictions we can all laugh about a few years later.

Comment: In your view its worth after earning 20 rep to talk & discuss about it in the chat room but which should not ask in superuser.com. So its closed then, when something is worth to ask in the community but asked in wrong place can be closed and should suggest in such a way to keep the users more interested and enthusiastic to come up with more questions but should not give minus points cause its worth to ask somewhere in the community. Dont you think community sites should improve in such way?

Comment: @user113701 Chat room is of no lasting value. On the main site, we try to build content that is *actually* useful. In chat, you can talk about whatever you want. That's the main difference.

Answer (score 3):

You keep coming back to how you are asking for an explanation of what the next generation of technology will be.

We don't know.  None of us do.  Oh, that won't stop any of us from supposing, or guessing, or wanting to discuss what it *might* be.  Any of us, including yourself, could do a few Google searches to provide examples of what the next technology might consist of... and some of them would be quite impressive.  But after all of that, none of it is going to produce a solid, exact answer of what the next technology **WILL** be.  That is the core of things.  What we would suppose, could get buried and never see the light of day in a year, replaced by something none of us saw.  That would make the answer useless.  Superuser is not a discussion forum.  It is a Question/Answer forum.

Yes, I know you asked a question, but there is no definitive answer to your question... only supposition.

The first example you gave, for why CPUs are still used instead of being replaced by GPUs, has definitive answers right now.  Maybe that will change in a few years, but then again, maybe CPUs will always continue to get more powerful and stay ahead... but the question was *not* about the future of GPUs.  It was not about the future of CPUs.  It was about the current state of CPUS in comparison to GPUS and why the latter has not replaced the former.

Can you see the difference now?  One is a comparison of two things and was dealt with current facts to provide a definitive answer.  Your question deals with future unknowns and guess work.  Nothing definitive.  It is because it was a speculative question, that it was closed.  It was not a good fit for what Superuser is all about.

Now... if you want to know why Superuser is not a site for discussions and speculative answers that result in open ended extensive conversations... that would be a very different question.